# How to set cookie for selenium test httprequest

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to using cookie to authenticate a login page with selenium test. I am using code of the form:

```
selenium.createCookie("name=Cookie", value);
selenium.open("http://localhost/sample/Login");
```

but no have result. Cannot login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `selenium.open` for a URL in the same domain as the cookie (in this case, "http://localhost/sample").  Then you can call `selenium.createCookie` with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Tks Joe Coder, With firefox or Chrome browser if i use selenium.open after selenium.createCookie it's OK but with IE it isn't . Why?

Comment: I don't know, IE sucks.  Haha.  Just stick to the Selenium docs and you'll be fine :)